# Adding Data to firebase Realtime Database showing Error

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app based on firebase Realtime database. I have set rules as given below:

```
{
// Allow anyone to read data, but only authenticated content owners can
// make changes to their data

  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        // or ".read": "auth.uid != null" for only authenticated users
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to add data by the following code in java. But getting Error.

```
myfire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = myfire.getReference("Users").child("Some Authentic User");
        //======================

        btnAdmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                stName = etName.getText().toString();
                stRoll = etRoll.getText().toString();


                etName.setText("");
                etRoll.setText("");


                myRef = myfire.getReference();
                myRef.child("201").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                       model model =new model();
                       model.setFb01name(stName);
                       model.setFb04roll(stRoll);
                        myRef.child("Basic").setValue(model);
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext                       (),"Sorry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }




                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext                       (),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }



                });
            }
        });
```

My model class goes like this:

```
public class model {

        String fb01name;
        String fb04roll;

        public model() {

        }

        public model(String fb01name, String fb04roll) {
                this.fb01name = fb01name;
                this.fb04roll = fb04roll;
        }



        public String getFb01name() {
                return fb01name;
        }

        public void setFb01name(String fb01name) {
                this.fb01name = fb01name;
        }

        public String getFb04roll() {
                return fb04roll;
        }

        public void setFb04roll(String fb04roll) {
                this.fb04roll = fb04roll;
        }
}
```

I cannot find the error. The logcat is blank.
I was successful in adding data previously .But after changing the rules it failed.I want the database path like this:

(Main Node)Users--

```
 (first Child)---Authenitic User(As added by "Add User")
     (second child)-----some id( like '201')
           (Targeted Children) 1 ------fb01name (and its value)
            2------fb04roll (and its value)
```

Can anybody will please guide me practically?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Also: showing a toast is good, but no replacement for logging the actual error you get from Firebase. At the very least your `onCancelled` should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext                       (),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Log.e("Database", "Error reading child 201", e.toException());
                    }`

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply @ Frank van Puffelen ...it displays the toast "error"  as I mentioned in the "OnCencelled" method.

Comment: OK. See my second comment about also logging that, as that will fix your `The logcat is blank."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `onCancelled` is called on your listener, that means that you don't have permission to read the data that you're trying to access. If you log the `databaseError.toException()` that you get in `onCancelled` you should also see that, as it should tell you that permission was denied.

Distilling your code down, you're attaching a listener to:

```
myRef = myfire.getReference();
myRef.child("201").addValueEventListener(...
```

So that is the path `/201` in the database, where indeed your rules don't grant anyone read access.

My best guess is that the `myRef = myfire.getReference();` line is a mistake, and removing it will lead to reading `/Users/Some Authentic User/201`, which is probably what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks...Now "onCancelled" is not being called. The toast in onDataChange is being displayed. But data  was actually NOT SAVED in firebase console .Still there is nothing in logcat.

Comment: That could well be, as it is totally possible that there were multiple problems in the code. I  recommend posting a new question for the remaining problem, and focusing on `child("Some Authentic User")` (as that value has to match the UID you check in your security rules).